# Use two entity fields in one form field

Tags: forms, symfony

I'd like to use one text form field to save data in two entity properties. However I didn't found any solution/hint which might lead to a clean implementation.

Consider the following example†:

- There is a Doctrine entity with two properties: count, unit
- A user enters "34 apples" in a simple text input field
- The DataTransformer (or whatever is appropriate) should transform this value in such a way that in the underlying entity count = '34' and unit = 'apple' is being saved.

Comment: A DataTransformer is what you want.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html

Comment: @Cerad, thank you for your suggestion. Is there a way to pass multiple entity properties to a DataTransformer?

Comment: Yep.  Typically an array but you can pass anything in and transform it.  Look around for some more concrete examples.

Answer (score 0):

you could have a field which is not mapped in the database and in the prePersist and preUpdate methods you would transform the data and save these in the appropriate fields. For example:

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class MyClass
{
    private $info;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="count", type="integer")
     */
    private $count;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="unit", type="string")
     */
    private $unit;

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function separateInfo(){
        $infoArray     = explode(' ', $this->info);
        $this->count   = $infoArray[0];
        $this->unit    = $infoArray[1];
    }
}
```

And in the form you only add the 'info' field:

```
class MyClassType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('info');
    }
}
```

This is not tested, but it's the idea which could help you.

I hope this be useful for you.

Kind regards.